# How can I make the Lux package work in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, graphics, jupyter-lab

I was trying to use the package called LUX for Python. I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/lux-org/lux). So it was pretty simple, I just had to import some csv and when I called my data, I would be able to see multiple graphs. The problem is that I do everything and nothing shows up for me.

I was using [Melbourne House Market data](https://www.kaggle.com/anthonypino/melbourne-housing-market), and this is my script so far:

```
# firstly, we install package and extensions
!pip install lux-api
!jupyter nbextension install --py luxwidget
!jupyter nbextension enable --py luxwidget

# then, load the packages
import lux
import pandas as pd

# load data
melb_data = pd.read_csv("melb_data.csv")
```

So far so good... at least, I thought so. After doing these things, when we see the tutorial mentioned in the begining of this question, it mentions that if we call the dataframe now, instead of appearing only the dataset, we would be able to see some graphics as well. But that didn't happen to me. I know screenshots are not the best choice, but this is what I see:

[image]

As you can see, there is the Toggle button, but it is only working to hide the table. there isn't the graphs I saw in the tutorial. I also tried to follow [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/intelligent-visual-data-discovery-with-lux-a-python-library-dc36a5742b2f) as well, but there isn't anything new there.

Any ideas on what I'm missing here? Why I can't find a way to make this package work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you have not installed the JuypterLab extension. It is described in the README file that you linked, [here](https://github.com/lux-org/lux#setup-in-jupyter-lab). You will need to execute the following two commands:

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
jupyter labextension install luxwidget
```

and then restart JupyterLab. The prerequisite here is having a JupyterLab 2.x or 3.x and Node.js installed (while many extensions for JupyterLab 3.x do not require node.js any longer, this one still does - as it seems).